# configure grub to work with either UEFI or PC BIOS boot

Tags: linux, grub, freebsd, grub2

Is there a way to use GRUB to boot in a system that will only boot in UEFI mode AND (without changing anything on the disk) also boot in a system that will only boot in PC BIOS (legacy) mode?

I want to build a disk image that will boot in either mode without having to reconfigure anything when moving the boot disk among a varied set of computers.  I am thinking of a configuration where it will try first one mode, then another if the first fails - say UEFI, then legacy PC BIOS (or vice versa).

This will typically be used to boot FreeBSD or Linux, but I think this should be independent of the desired Operating System that ultimately gets loaded.

I am currently using GPT partition tables and have both an EFI System Partition (ESP - mounted on `/boot/efi` when booted into linux, for instance), and a non-ESP boot partition (mounted on `/boot` when booted in linux).  There is also the a partition for GRUB that GRUB calls the "BIOS Boot Partition" (`parted` uses the `bios_grub` flag for that partition).  [[1]]

I am trying to understand if GRUB can be configured with multiple targets (it looks like `grub2-install` only picks the last `--target` if more than one is specified) or use a fallback mechanism to achieve this goal (or maybe chain loading can be used?).

Right now, I have to run `grub2-install --target=x86_64-efi <disk>` before moving the disk to a UEFI system and `grub2-install --target=i386-pc <disk>` before moving to a legacy PC BIOS system.  That works fine (without having to change anything else), but I would like to know if there is a way to avoid having to make that configuration change before moving the disk.

[[1]] **Edit:**
To be a little more specific about the current GPT configuration...

The ESP GPT GUID is C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B (happens to be partition #2).

The BIOS Boot Partition GPT GUID is 21686148-6449-6E6F-744E-656564454649 (happens to be partition #1).

The /boot filesystem has a GPT GUID of EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7 (happens to be partition #4 and is an ext4 filesystem on a linux system).

When using the `parted` utility, the "flag" for the ESP is `boot`, the "flag" for the BIOS Boot Partition is `bios_grub`, and the "flag" for /boot is `legacy_boot` (I don't think GRUB cares about that `legacy_boot` flag, so I think it neither helps nor hurts my desired goal).

Answer (score 2):

> Right now, I have to run grub2-install --target=x86_64-efi  before moving the disk to a UEFI system and grub2-install --target=i386-pc  before moving to a legacy PC BIOS system. That works fine (without having to change anything else), but I would like to know if there is a way to avoid having to make that configuration change before moving the disk.

You can already do both, they do not overwrite each other's files: 1) install for UEFI; 2) install for BIOS; 3) now you have a disk that has GRUB for UEFI *and* BIOS.

It's the subsequent *configuration* (the `grub.cfg` that's made by `grub-mkconfig`) that needs to be written carefully so as to work on both systems. With file-based boot (where GRUB itself loads the Linux kernel) it should be fine, but for some operating systems you may need to manually create a custom 'menuitem' using GRUB's (very shell-like) conditionals to do either this or that depending on firmware type – that is, instead of relying entirely on grub-mkconfig, you may need to maintain a hand-written grub.cfg (or at least parts of it).

> I don't think GRUB cares about that legacy_boot flag

It doesn't; this is the direct equivalent of the MBR 'active/bootable' flag (which GRUB doesn't care about in MBR either), and in practice it is only used by Syslinux's GPT-compatible MBR BIOS bootcode (gptmbr.bin).

Comment: One potential problem is that some legacy BIOS versions might look at the partition table in the MBR and refuse to boot if there is no active MBR partition. If you need to support that case, you would need to create a hybrid MBR which has an entry with the “active” flag set.